# unable to insert in MS access DB

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans

I am trying to insert into MS access DB from a JSP page using JDBC, ucanaccess driver. No errors are sown but values are not getting inserted into DB

while using similar code in order to show table values(using SELECT * from table), that is running fine. But I am not able to insert in that table

```
<%@taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<%@page import ="java.sql.*"%> 
<html>
<head><title>MS Access Insert</title></head>
<body> 
<table border=1>
<tr><th>Student ID</th><th>Student Name</th></tr>
<% 
Connection cn=null; 
{ 
try 
{ 
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver"); 

String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + "C:/Users/6136532/Desktop/New folder/(4)/studentDB.mdb";

cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url); 
Statement st=cn.createStatement();
st.execute("INSERT INTO studentDB VALUES (100, 18, 'Zara', 'Ali', prasad)");
%>

<%      
//rs.close();
st.close();
cn.close();
} 
catch(Exception e) 
{ 
e.printStackTrace(); 
} 
}
%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd be VERY, VERY concerned about using MSAccess for this type of task, as it only supports a limited number of active connections.  But, you will probably need to commit your transaction before you close the connnection

Comment: check this out http://mrbool.com/jsp-database-access-how-to-access-database-from-a-jsp-page/30869

Comment: I am using same code along with query (Select * from tablename);

Answer (score 1):

You can't just insert an unknown parameter prasad. So either:

```
st.execute("INSERT INTO studentDB VALUES (100, 18, 'Zara', 'Ali', 'prasad')");
```

or:

```
String prasad = "Prasad Telang";
st.execute("INSERT INTO studentDB VALUES (100, 18, 'Zara', 'Ali', '" + prasad + "')");
```

Comment: Can you please tell about using - 

st.execute("INSERT INTO Table (Namee, Phone, Email) Values ('"+ name2.value + "' , '" + phone2.value + "' ,  '" + email2.value + "');");

name2.value is value of some text field used in the same jsp page

it is unable to identify name - No current context.

and I am using this inside a <script> </script> while a function is called

Comment: Sorry, no. I use neither Java nor jsp.

Comment: @PrasadTelang : Typo ? `Namee` .

Comment: @moskito-x not a typo. I used double e because name is a keyword in access. Code below worked :)

String name2 = request.getParameter("name");
String phone2 = request.getParameter("phone");
String email2 = request.getParameter("email");

st.executeUpdate("insert into sectable (namee, phone, email, curd) values ('" + name2 + "','" + phone2 + "','" + email2 + "', CURDATE())");

Comment: @PrasadTelang : as in the answer seen remove `;` inside the query.